# curl php comparar resultado

Tags: php

gracias por leer mi post, bueno:

Tengo un php con curl el cual hace una consulta  y devuelve un resultado.

```
{"Consultar":{"Apellidos":"FRANCISCO ","vip":false,"Nombre":"nombre "}}
```

Actualmente tengo que comparar el numero de usuario y si es vip hacer una redirección a una página, y si no lo es a otra diferente.

**¿Cómo comparo si es VIP con el resultado que me devuelve arriba?**

y en caso de que el resultado sea "false" haga una redireccion y si es "true" haga otra redirección diferente?

```
<?php 
$user= $_GET['user'];

    $curl = curl_init();
        $request =  '';
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'login');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['content-type: application/json']);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    if($err) {
        echo 'Curl Error: ' . $err;
    } else {
        // header('content-type: application/json');
        $response = json_decode($result, true);
        $token = $response['AuthenticateResult']['AuthToken']; 
        curl_close($curl);




        
/* *************************************************************************************************************************************************** */




        /*SEGUNDA LLAMADA PARA OBTENER EL USUARIO*/
        $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
              CURLOPT_URL => "consultarusuario",
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
              CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
              CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
              CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
              CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
              CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{ \"usuario\":\"" .$user. "\" }",
              CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    "authorization: Bearer $token",
                    "content-type: application/json",
                  ),
            ));
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            $err = curl_error($curl);

            if ($err) {
              echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
            } else {
              echo $response;
            }
            curl_close($curl);
        }
?>
```

he intentado algo pero se lo salta, gracias por la ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. Hablas de comparar primero el número de usuario ¿? Pero no hay ninguna información sobre "número de usuario".

Comment: @A.Cedano post editado, queria decir ¿Cómo comparo si es VIP con el resultado que me devuelve arriba? y si es vip que me rediriga a una pagina y si no a otra , gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que `$response` vale esto:

```
$response='{"Consultar":{"Apellidos":"FRANCISCO ","vip":false,"Nombre":"nombre "}}';
```

Puedes aplicarle `json_decode()` para trabajar con un JSON y buscar los datos.

Por ejemplo:

```
        if ($err) {
          echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
          $json=json_decode($response);
          #Asignas la URL con un ternario
          $url=($json->Consultar->vip) ? "www.url.cuando.sea.true" : "www.url.cuando.sea.false";
          #Rediriges usando $url
          header("Location: $url");
          exit();
        }
```

**PD:**
Para que tu código no quede en el limbo en caso de error, si estás trabajando con redirecciones, deberías considerar aplicarlas también en caso de que haya errores de cURL.

Por ejemplo:

```
        if ($err) {
          $url="www.url.cuando.error";
        } else {
          $json=json_decode($response);
          #Asignas la URL con un ternario
          $url=($json->Consultar->vip) ? "www.url.cuando.sea.true" : "www.url.cuando.sea.false";
        }
        #Rediriges usando $url, fuera del if
        header("Location: $url");
        exit();
```

Comment: gracias! claro, en el         if ($err) {
añadir una redireccion . no ?

Comment: @ELE puedes simplemente asignar un valor para `$url` ahí  y hacer la redirección al final de todas las comparaciones, así usas una sola variable (`$url`)  de comodín para saber a qué URL se hará el Location al final del código. Debes quitar el `echo` y cualquier salida por pantalla.

Comment: @ELE revisa la respuesta editada, al final.

Comment: si si, a eso me referia, perfecto funciona correctamente, mil gracias :)